# Installing Python egg dependencies without apt-get

Tags: python, installation, packaging, setuptools

I've got a Python module which is distributed on PyPI, and therefore installable using `easy_install`. It depends on lxml, which in turn depends on libxslt1-dev. I'm unable to install libxslt1-dev with `easy_install`, so it doesn't work to put it in `install_requires`. Is there any way I can get setuptools to install it instead of resorting to `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)** can only install Python packages that in the package index you are using, either the default index of the one you specify with `easy_install -i http://myindex.site/index`.

Any non-Python dependencies have to be installed using the standard installation package for the platform (apt-get on Debian based Linux distros). `libxml2` and `libxslt` fall into this category so you should install these in the standard way.

Answer (score 1):

It's better use apt-get to install lxml (or the python packages that has c extensions) and then pull pure python package from pypi. Also I generally try to avoid using easy_install for top level install, I rather create a virtual env using virtualenv and then use easy_install created by virtualenv to keep my setups clean.

This strategy is working successfully for me for couple of production environments.